# FFMPEG - Any suggestions on how to achieve a lookahead with sidechaincompress?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg-filters, help

I need [sidechaincompress](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sidechaincompress) (i'll call it SCC) to look ahead 750ms and smoothly drop the audio level in that lookahead window.

I'm currently using this:

```
-filter_complex "0:a]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.01:attack=750:release=750:knee=8:ratio=5[comp]
```

There are other filters in the -filters_complex chain, but I'm only showing the SCC as everything else is working brilliantly.

I was thinking of adding extra time to the release and then finding a way to offset the SCC track when I use amix later on in the filter chain, as well as finding a way to smoothly drop the volume when the SCC is triggered, as currently it drops the volume really quickly.